# simple xml attirubute parsing

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

How am I able to get this using my code from this XML:

```
<lfm status="ok"><results for="sub bass monster ragga">
<opensearch:Query role="request" searchTerms="sub bass monster ragga" startPage="1"/>   <opensearch:totalResults>2</opensearch:totalResults><opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex><opensearch:itemsPerPage>30</opensearch:itemsPerPage><trackmatches>

$count = $xml->results[0]->opensearch:totalResults  ???
```

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement::children()` maybe of help, but please post your complete, or at least well-formed, XML including the namespace definition of `opensearch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't work with documents containing namespaces using SimpleXML.

You need to load your doc with [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and then use [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php).